# Can Netty client reconnect the server in ChannelHandler with it's ChannelHandlerContext?

Tags: netty

I want to implement a disconnect/reconenct mechanism.

I've seen that most of the time the reconnect will create a new Bootstrap, I 'm wondering is it possible to do the reconnect in ChannelHandler.

For example, if the client catch an WRITE_IDLE event, can it just close the channel and reconnect it in ChannelHandler as bellow?

```
@Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleState state= ((IdleStateEvent) evt).state();
            if (state == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                // read timeout, break the channel
                System.out.println("client write timeout");
                SocketAddress remoteAddress = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
                // close channel
                ctx.channel().close();
                // reconnect
                ctx.connect(remoteAddress);

            }
        }
    }
```

I tested it several times, but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

A Channel and ChannelHandlerContext can not be reconnected. Once its closed its "life-time" is over. You will need to bootstrap again.

Comment: How  can I perceive the channel's state change in bootstrap? Should I check if the channel is active every time I want to send a message?